# How to run a JET2 project templates without run an Eclipse application or OSGi framework?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jet

When I run an JET2 project as an JET Transformation application I get this error:

```
"Could not load JET template loader"
```

However, my project is executed correctly when I run it as an Eclipse application. This is costly in terms of change, because every change I obligue to launch a new instance of Eclipse.

Comment: Plase also state your question explicitly in the question's body (and not just in the title).

Comment: the question is: how can I run my JET project without using the  eclipse  or OSGI runtime environment

Answer (score 0):

I run a light-weight version of JET using [tika-manel-jet-plugin](http://network.tikalk.com/release/tikal-maven-jet-plugin/) to create code that creates code that can run without additional libraries used in my [JPA Annotation Processor](http://site.trajano.net/jpa-apt/).  Mind you this is not the complete JET, it is JET re-implemented using ANTLR